# while importing seaborn i was getting this error

Tags: python-3.x

```
import seaborn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>
    from .morestats import *
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py", line 12, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.decorators import setastest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow and Happy New Year!

I think you haven't installed `numpy.testing.decorators`.

Run `pip install numpy` and retry.

Comment: Numpy deprecated and removed `numpy.testing.decorators`.